# “The JSON value could not be converted to System.String” when attempting to call controller endpoint

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've been trying to create a simple API,
I manage to make the `Get` work just fine but whenever I try to work with `Post` or `Put` I can't get it to work.
I'm trying to post/put a JSON and getting it as a string in my controller.
I'm using Postman and Insomnia to test (I precise I turned of SSL verification for both since I run in local).
Here is my controller:

```
[Route("backoffice/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AddQuestionController : ControllerBase
{
    private IQuestionRepository _questionRepository;

    public AddQuestionController(IQuestionRepository questionRepository)
    {
        _questionRepository = questionRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(questionRepository));

    }

    [ProducesResponseType((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddQuestion([FromBody] string question)
    {
        Question q = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Question>(question);
        await Task.Run(() => _questionRepository.InsertOne(q));
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

[image: postman]

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|a0b79872-4e41e975d19e251e.",
    "errors": {
        "$": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."
        ]
    }
}
```

So then I thought it's because the `Json` format in postman. But then I tried the `text` format
and this happened:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "status": 415,
    "traceId": "|a0b79873-4e41e975d19e251e."
}
```

And every time it doesn't even reach the first line of my controller.
Can someone tell me what I did wrong here? Is it my controller? Is it my way of using Postman?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The model binder is unable to map/bind the sent data to the controller parameters

Your action expects a simple string from the request body

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AddQuestion([FromBody] string question)
```

But you sent a complex object

```
{ "test" : "test" }
```

You might have gotten a match if the property name(s) had matched

For example

```
{ "question" : "test" }
```

Since the model binder will take property names into consideration when matching parameters.

if you want to receive a raw string then you need to send a valid raw JSON string

```
"{ \"test\": \"test \"}"
```

That is properly escaped.

Another options is to use a complex object for the parameter

```
class Question  {
    public string test { get; set; }
    //...other properties
}
```

that matches the expected data

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AddQuestion([FromBody] Question question) {
    string value = question.test;

    //...
}
```

The model binder will bind the data and pass it to the action parameter(s).

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

Comment: I don't understand. I'm trying to send a json to my controller and retrieving it as a string not to bind anything.

Comment: @Platypus the model binder can do that for you since you are already trying deserializing it yourself.

Comment: thank you the model binder work, do you have any idea why i can't just retrieve it as a string ? even by passing a string in postman ?

Comment: Hi @Nkosi I have somehow a similar issue. 
I have the following API endpoint `` [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreateSkill([FromBody] Employee employee)`
The employee object class has the following properties `   public int Id { get; set; }` `public string FirstName { get; set; }` ` public string Surname { get; set; }` `public List<EmployeeSkillMiddleTable> EmployeeSkillMiddleTables { get; set; }`

where `EmployeeSkillMiddleTables ` is the representation of the middle table between a many-to-many relationship. ..->

_is getting continue to next comment_

Comment: that middle table contains the following properties ` public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public int SkillId { get; set; }`

So, I Use Postman to create a new employee entry and also pass the id values on property of the middletable 
the json that I use is: `{
    "firstName": "first",
    "Surname": "last",
    "employeeSkillMiddleTables": [4,11]
}`
with its navigation properties

Comment: and I have the following error ` "errors": {
        "$.employeeSkillMiddleTables[0]": [
            "`The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List1[Models.EmployeeSkillMiddleTable]. Path: $.employeeSkillMiddleTables[0] | LineNumber: 3 | BytePositionInLine: 35."
        ]` 
could you help me on how to pass those values to the endpoint ?

Comment: @noruk it is difficult to understand your problem in the comments. If you were to post an actual question it would help to better understand the actual issue and will allow others to provide more help.

Comment: Sir, You are genius. thanks.

Comment: @Nkosi - maybe I'm missing something, but using `{ "question" : "test" }` still fails when the method signature is defined as `([FromBody] string question)` - thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks *@Nkosi* for identifying the issue and providing the article [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding).

Since I spent a lot of time going through outdated examples on how to call an API, here's my code for reference (as of Sep-2020):

On the API project, I used the **[BindProperty]** attribute on the properties of the model class.

```csharp
    // ASP.NET CORE API - C# model

    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using System;
    
    namespace MyTestAPI.Models
    {
        public partial class MyTest
        {
            [BindProperty]
            public int TestId { get; set; }
            [BindProperty]
            public string Message { get; set; }
            [BindProperty]
            public Guid? CreatedBy { get; set; }
            [BindProperty]
            public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

On the API controller, the **mytest** class is automatically deserialized because of the property attributes of the **MyTest** model class:

```csharp
// ASP.NET CORE API - C# controller

using Dapper;
using HangVue.API.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MyTestAPI.Models;

namespace HangVue.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {     

       [HttpPost]
       public void Post([FromBody] MyTest mytest)
       {

           var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
           parameters.Add("@pMessage", mytest.Message, System.Data.DbType.String, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);
           parameters.Add("@CreatedBy", mytest.CreatedBy.ToString(), System.Data.DbType.String, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);

           string sql = "[dbo].[uspTest]";

           using (var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(*** SQL_conn_string_goes_here ***))
           {
             var affectedRows = conn.Query(sql, parameters, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
           }
       }
    }  
}
```

On the client side, I'm using [Xamarin.Forms](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/xamarin/xamarin-forms) with [RestSharp](https://restsharp.dev) to invoke my API. The **AccessToken** is required because I'm using [Azure AD B2C authentication](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/external-identities/b2c/).

```csharp
// Xamarin.Forms - C# Client (iOS + Android)

using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace YourApp.Services
{
    public static class TestServices
    {   

       public async static Task<string> NewTest(int iTestId, string sMessage, Guid? gCreatedBy, DateTime dTimestamp)
       {
          try
          {
             var mytest = new Models.MyTest 
             {
                TestId = iTestId,
                Message = sMessage,
                CreatedBy = gCreatedBy,
                Timestamp = dTimestamp
             };

             // Client --- API end-point example:  https://yourAPIname.azurewebsites.net/
             RestSharp.RestClient client = new RestClient(*** https://Your_API_base_end_point_goes_here ***);
            
             // Request 
             RestSharp.RestRequest request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("api/test", RestSharp.Method.POST, RestSharp.DataFormat.Json);
             request.AddParameter("Authorization", "Bearer " + *** Your_AccessToken_goes_here ***, RestSharp.ParameterType.HttpHeader);
             request.AddHeader("Content-Type","application/json; CHARSET=UTF-8");
             request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
             request.AddJsonBody(mytest);

             // Invoke
             RestSharp.IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

             if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
             {
                *** do something ***    
                return *** a string *** ;
             }
             else
             {
                *** do something ***
                return *** a string *** ;
             }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
             *** do something ***
          }
       }
    }
}
```